# How to use serilog message templates with loggly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog, loggly

I want to use Serilog message templates with Loggly.

I have configured Loggly with Serilog into my application.

```
var logglySettings = new LogglySettings();
configuration.GetSection("Serilog:Loggly").Bind(logglySettings);
this.SetupLogglyConfiguration(logglySettings);
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .CreateLogger();
```

But I am not able to send multiple properties to loggly.com

For example I want to use:

```
public void Error<T, T1>(string message, T property0, T1 property1)
{
    Log.Error(message, property0, property1);
}
```

I am able to send multiple properties as

```
 return this.logger.Error("Could not save data.", new { Exception = ex, RequestData = requestData });
```

But this does not fit into Serilog pattern.

I wanted to use Serilog logging pattern as:

```
public void Error<T, T1>(string message, T property0, T1 property1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide a message template that includes all of the properties you want to log rather than just the message itself, e.g.

```cs
Log.Error("Error while saving {RequestData}: {Exception}", requestData, exception);
```

Since there's an explicit overload of `Log.Error` that accepts an exception argument, I'd recommend using that instead, as this will enable cleaner presentation and more deep destructuring (e.g., via [Demystify](https://github.com/nblumhardt/serilog-enrichers-demystify)). You can also force deep-destructuring the request data using the `@` template character if you want more than just its `ToString()` representation, e.g.

```cs
Log.Error(exception, "Failed to save {@RequestData}", requestData)
```

Alternatively, if you specifically don't want to include the request data in the message itself you can add it as context information, e.g.

```cs
Log.ForContext("RequestData", requestData, destructureObjects: true)
    .Error(exception, "Could not save data.")
```